# Creating object of Private Inner class from other class

Tags: java, android, reflection, junit, private-members

I have a scenario where there is a public outer class and a private inner class. now i want to create an object of this private inner class for unit testing the methods in it.

```
public class MyOuterClass {
    public MyOuterClass() { }

    private class MyInnerClass {
        public MyInnerClass() { }
    }
}
```

This is the scenario where I am trying to create an object of "MyInnerClass" from some other test class. I found solution for creating object of class with private constructor but that is not what i required. please help me with this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to unit test private inner classes. That should be telling you your class design is wrong (or your testing approach is wrong).

Comment: class must not have `()`

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Make the inner class package private (the default access level instead) and you can access it by putting your test code in the same package.
2. Use reflection to access it by over-riding the access restriction.
3. Rethink your architecture. It's possible you might need to directly test private inner classes but it would be more usual to test the outer class and by doing that also test the inner one.

Comment: +1 for points #1 and #3 (particularly #3). Option #2 is just grim.

Comment: @Tim for using #3 For my scenario the inner class is a class extending Handler which overrides the handle message method, and this cannot be called directly unless u create the object of inner class.

Comment: @tim and we cannot change the access modifiers for all the cases where ever this happens right. so i think using reflection would be a better way. Can u please post a sample code snippet as iam new to reflection.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials around, for example google found this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html

Comment: In any of the tutorial, i did not found creating object of private inner  class.. this link u suggested also has only about fields and methods and private constructors. but not what i required.. sorry..:\

Comment: So do some searches...for example "java reflection access private inner class" gives as a first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112166/instantiate-private-inner-class-with-java-reflection

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept of `private` objects is that it can only be accessed by the class that it's encapsulated in. You cannot directly create an instance of a private object from another class.

Comment: If it is so, how can u achieve 100% code coverage in unit testing, for such types of code there are methods like reflection for accessing private members but iam not sure how to do that for this scenario.