# Java reflection : how to call a method with private interface as argument?

Tags: java, reflection, interface

In Java, I usually call a method by Reflection which uses an `interface` as argument by building my arguments using:

```
Method method = theClass.getMethod("methodName", new Class[]{ IAnyInterface.class });
```

But I don't know how to do this when the `interface` is nested in a private class: `JSomething.INestedInterface`, where `JSomething` is `private`:

```
private class JSomething {
   public void init(INestedInterface iSomething) {
       ...
   }

   public interface INestedInterface {
       public void notify();
   }

   ...
}
```

Here using this doesn't even compile as the interface is not accessible :

```
Method method = theClass.getMethod("init", new Class[]{JSomething.INestedInterface.class});
```

I've created a Proxy handler ready to be called, but I'm stuck trying to build a `class` argument when I can't use the nested interface name, any advice?

Comment: Is your private class a inner class ? If it is , see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112166/instantiate-private-inner-class-with-java-reflection

Comment: Do you need other clarifications?

Comment: Thanks. The `private` does not really exists, it was a figure of speach. The real `class` is in a file with a different package name, making the class private by default. It works fine now, I was not aware of the `$` operator ^^. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmh, are you sure your code compiles by prefixing the class with `private`?
That visibility modifier **isn't allowed** for first-level classes. Per `JLS 8.1.1`

> The access modifiers `protected` and `private` pertain only to **member**
>   classes within a directly enclosing class declaration.

---

But anyway, you can extract the `Class` via Reflection, too ;)

```
final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("your.package.JSomething$INestedInterface");
theClass.getMethod("methodName", new Class[]{ clazz });
```

Or if your `JSomething` class is an *inner* `static` class by itself

```
final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("your.package.WrapperClass$JSomething$INestedInterface");
theClass.getMethod("methodName", new Class[]{ clazz });
```

Note that each "nesting level" is marked by a `$` symbol, and the `String` you're passing in is called class' *binary name* (see [JLS 13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1)).

> The binary name of a top level type (§7.6) is its canonical name (§6.7).
>
> The binary name of a member type (§8.5, §9.5) consists of the binary
>   name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by `$`, followed by the
>   simple name of the member.

---

And by the way, `getMethod` accepts a var-arg parameter, so you can just submit a single value

```
theClass.getMethod("methodName", clazz);
```

Comment: Thanks. The `private` does not really exists, it was a figure of speach. The real `class` is in a file with a different package name, making the class private by default. It works fine now, I was not aware of the `$` operator ^^. Thanks again.